# Why can't the Doctor visit a particular point in his timeline to return to Gallifrey (at least temporarily)?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel, paradox

We already know the Doctor never follows the rules of space-time, so why is Gallifrey inaccessible? Shouldn't he be able to, you know, travel to a point in his past when Gallifrey still existed in that universe? We've already seen that the Doctor and his past incarnations can interact without major consequences. Would this create too much of a rip in time? Or has the Doctor just not had the mind to do so?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question has [already been asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/43133/13941), and Stack Exchange likes to keep all the answers to one question in one place, so this version will probably be closed soon. Don't let that discourage you, please; it just means your question is pre-answered!

Comment: Because The Doctor follows some sense of rules which is that he is usually never allowed to cross his own timeline...  Almost all times that The Doctor has done so was through plot devices such as The Three Doctors were called together because there was something threatening our universe from outside of it.. Mainly Omega... Same thing with Day of The Doctor, The Moment allowed him to meet his other future selves to decide if he wanted to destroy Gallifrey.